# substituting a string with cmd with wildchar

Tags: cmd, substitution

i have a text file with me which contains some lines

```
line1
line2
helloabcd
line4
```

i want to create a batch file to edit the helloabcd line with say `%this%` but i dont know what `abcd` is all i know is `hello`. so how can i do it?

i tried using fart.exe, but it never substituted when there was a wildcard

```
fart.exe txt1.txt hello* %this%
```

can it be done using pure cmd, or even with fart?

thanks in advance for your reply

Edit: ok tried `fart.exe txt1.txt hello %this%` but now i got `%this%abcd` instead of `%this%`

Comment: What is `%this%` in this setting? Batch variable or string?

Comment: a string `set this=wqreqwrq`

Comment: all right batch variable containing a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off &setlocal
set "this=wqreqwrq"
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('^<txt1.txt findstr /n "^"') do (
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "line=!line:*:=!"
    if not "!line!"=="!line:hello=!" set "line=%this%"
    (echo(!line!)>>output.txt
    endlocal
)
```

Output is in `output.txt`.

Edit: add. "!" removed.

Comment: what if instead of `hello`, it is entered by user

Comment: ie `set /p replace=enter what to replace`

Comment: You can put the search string also in a variable: `set /p "search=enter what to search: "` .... `if not "!line!"=="!line:%search%=!" ...`.